# How can I split a sum between an unknown amount of rows in a dataframe unequally, giving more weight to rows that are higher?

Tags: python, dataframe

My current code aims to determine how many stocks you should purchase by giving a equal portion of total portfolio size to each stock and then calculate how many shares to purchase.

```
position_size = float(portfolio_size)/len(hqm_dataframe.index)
for i in hqm_dataframe.index:
    hqm_dataframe.loc[i,'Number of Shares to Buy']      =math.floor(position_size/hqm_dataframe.loc[i,'Price'])
hqm_dataframe
```

Is it possible to not divide the initial portfolio size equally and instead divide it unequally with weight given to how high the row is in the dataframe. For example, given that there is a total of 4 stocks, give the first row 40% of capital, second row 30%, third row 20% and fourth row 10%.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt for loop it out:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import math

# Get data for FAANG stocks
stocks = ['META', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'NFLX', 'GOOG']

data = yf.download(stocks, start='2023-08-19', end='2023-08-19')['Close']
hqm_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data).T
hqm_dataframe.columns = ['price']

# Portfolio size
portfolio_size = 100000
desired_stock_weights = [0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

# Splitting the portfolio size by weight
for i, stock in enumerate(stocks):
    position_size = portfolio_size * desired_stock_weights[i]
    hqm_dataframe.loc[stock, 'num_shares_to_buy'] = math.floor(position_size / hqm_dataframe.loc[stock, 'price'])

hqm_dataframe
```

**Output:**

| index | price | num_shares_to_buy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 174.49000549316406 | 286.0 |
| AMZN | 133.22000122070312 | 75.0 |
| GOOG | 128.11000061035156 | 78.0 |
| META | 283.25 | 35.0 |
| NFLX | 404.5299987792969 | 24.0 |

Comment: What could I do if the total number of stocks is a variable so I cannot simply define the desired stock weights beforehand.

Comment: You can dynamically calculate the weights based on the number of stocks and your desired distribution.